# Can we write SQL query instead of CQL?

Tags: jdbc, neo4j, bolt

I am using JDBC driver (org.neo4j.jdbc.bolt.BoltDriver) to connect to neo4j (jdbc link url : [neo4j-jdbc-driver-link](https://neo4j.com/blog/official-neo4j-jdbc-driver-3-0/)) . Could see we need to write SQL while executing query.

Can we write a SQL query instead of CQL like `SELECT p.* FROM products as p;`?

Comment: Note that Cypher isn't hard to pick up. The equivalent of that query is, assuming we have :Product nodes: `MATCH (p:Product) RETURN p`, though note this will only be a single column for `p` with a map of properties per row. As Luanne says, Neo4j doesn't have a concept of tables, there's nothing nailing down the properties a node of a particular label must have. SQL can dynamically infer the columns since that's defined in the products table. That doesn't exist in Neo4j, so that can't be inferred (without a more complex query and a label scan), and even then that wouldn't be dynamic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it accepts only Cypher. There is no concept of tables in Neo4j. The docs are at https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-jdbc/